# Creating Object array using lodash

Tags: lodash

I want to create an object array from a user collection. Following is the linq query in C#. I want help in creating the collection using lodash

```
var result = from user in Users
   select new
   {
       Name = user.Name,
       UserId= user.Id
   };
return result;
```

Comment: Thanks Hardy for fixing typos, i will be careful next time. @Quy is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it using _.map

```
_.map(Users, function (user, index) {
            return { Name: user.Name, UserId: user.Id }; });
```